# Transmission Line: Converting from impedance to admittance. Why?

Tags: transmission-line

If we want to find the input impedance of this given transmission line problem, why is it advantageous to switch the quantities from impedance to admittance?

[image: Transmission line circuit problem]

Comment: Because when you have parallel circuit elements, admittances can be simply added.

Answer (score 1):

The left half of the line is loaded by the right half in parallel with the 30Ohm resistor. In admittance domain you can simply add that resistor to the admittance of the right part by increasing the real part. The needed increment is 50/30 = 1,67 in relative units and you get the admittance of the right half in relative units from Smiths chart.

You can use the same chart for impedances and admittances (rotate 180 degr) and you can even calculate the admittance of ZL with the chart (=find the same reflection factor). Check this if, you didn't know it before:

[Example Admittance Calculations with the Smith Chart](http://www.ittc.ku.edu/~jstiles/723/handouts/Example%20Admittance%20Calculations%20with%20the%20Smith%20Chart.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

It's because of what @Stefan Wyss said. It makes the math easy.

I wrote microwave simulation algorithms for a while and one of the first bits of code I wrote was converting to/from S, Z, Y, ABCD, h, g parameters. Using the right form let's you easily combine series, parallel, etc structures to get to a final impedance or voltage or current, etc.

The graphical/Smith chart answer is nice, too, and says the same thing in a different way.